# Why don't AsyncTasks always work within an onClickListener?

Tags: android, methods, onclick, android-asynctask, onclicklistener

I have noticed a this over the last few months. If I set a clickListener on a button to execute an AsyncTask, it doesn't always get executed. I solve the problem by wrapping the line of code that executes the AsyncTask in a method.

Here's the code that doesn't work all of the time:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new CustomAsyncTask().execute();
        }
    });
```

Here's my fix:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            executeAsyncTask();
        }
    });

public void executeAsyncTask(){
    new CustomAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

I  haven't noticed the pattern as to when it does and doesn't break, but I'm wondering if anyone else has noticed this?

Also, if anyone has an explanation as to why this happens that would be cool too.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here's the CustomAsyncTask (I know it's not being called all of the time because it doesn't print anything)

```
private class CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.i("CustomAsyncTask", "doInBackground");

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is customAsyncTask a subclass of the activity or just a class?

Comment: It's a subclass, but it can be a subclass of the activity or not, the same problem occurs. I've added that class to the initial post now.

Comment: Did you tried with `default` or `public` access level of CustomAsyncTask?

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev, Yes I have. It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @NotACleverMan am I right that it's executed for the first time and then stops? Or it's getting executed randomly?

Comment: I set the onClickListener in the onStart() of the Activity. Sometimes the AsyncTask gets executed when I click the button. When it doesn't, it sometimes gets executed when the activity stops or sometimes it just never gets executed at all.

Comment: Oh and if it works, it works for the lifetime of the Activity. If it doesn't work, it doesn't work for the lifetime of the Activity also.

Comment: @NotACleverMan put breakpoint at the line where task is created. Maybe your `onClick` isn't even called?